# Is method org.osgi.framework.Version.toString() thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, osgi

Method `org.osgi.framework.Version.toString()`was known to cause performance problems (see [see Bug 324331 - redundant Strings created from Version.toString](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324331)). In order to resolve this issue the method was changed and now it utilizes lazy initialization with data race  (probably for performance improvement)

```
// OSGi Service Platform Release 4 Version 4.3 Core Companion Code 
public String toString() {
    if (versionString != null) {
        return versionString;
    }
    int q = qualifier.length();
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(20 + q);
    result.append(major);
    result.append(SEPARATOR);
    result.append(minor);
    result.append(SEPARATOR);
    result.append(micro);
    if (q > 0) {
        result.append(SEPARATOR);
        result.append(qualifier);
    }
    return versionString = result.toString();
}
```

This is, as I believe, not thread-safe because reads of `versionString` field can be reordered and the method can return `null` value. Am I right? Or maybe it doesn't matter because it's never called without proper synchronization?

**Update**

According to [this](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/benign-data-races-in-java.html) blog post by Jeremy Manson, who is one of the authors of the Chapter 17 of the JLS on concurrency, it can actually happen.

Comment: I am the author of this code. I can see that via the Jeremy Manson blog post that there is a potential, if however small, issue here. I will update this code (and hashCode for R6) to avoid this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more about caching than laziness.

But you are right, it can return null according to Java Memory Model

```
StringversionString;

public String toString() {
    if (versionString != null) {
        return versionString;  // can return null here!!
    }
```

In theory it could be transformed to

```
    String tmp1 = versionString;  // reads null
    String tmp2 = versionString;  // reads non-null
    if(tmp2!=null)
        return tmp1;              // return null!
```

However probably no actual JVM will ever do that, so this bug probably never realizes.

Nevertheless, the "right" thing to do is

```
public String toString() {
    String tmp = versionString;
    if (tmp != null) {
        return tmp;
    }
```

---

The last line is fine though

```
    return versionString = result.toString();
```

it does not read `versionString`, it's equivalent to

```
    String tmp3 = result.toString();
    versionString = tmp3;
    return tmp3;
```

Interestingly, even if we do

```
    versionString = result.toString();   // [w]
    return versionString;                // [r]
```

it is still safe. The last read must not return null, because [w] happens-before [r].

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. The only way the first if statement could return null would be if another thread assigned null between the time of the if evaluation and the execution of the return, right? As the provided example shows, null will never be assigned (assuming no other code modifies versionString)